# Gem creates MySQL Error Messages due to different fieldnames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am playing around with the Acts-As-Taggable Rails gem. I am getting the following messages because I believe that the tags model is looking for 'post_id' which does not exist (instead 'id' within the Posts model/table).

Do I need to modify the model or the controller to get this to work?

The error occurs when I attempt to show the post.

Update:
- The error appears to be caused by the post view (show.html.erb). The post view refers to the post model (tag_list).

Error:

```
 Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'taggings.post_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`post_id` = 4
```

Post Controller (show);

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @post }
   end
 end
```

Post show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |post_form| %>
..
<div class="field">
  <%= post_form.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
  <%= post_form.text_field :tag_list %>
</div>
```

Post Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title, :tag_list #:tags_attributes

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  def self.tagged_with(name)
Tag.find_by_name!(name).posts
  end

  def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
        joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
  end

  def tag_list
    tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end

 def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

#Validations
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
        :length => { :minimum => 5 }

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

#  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => :true,
#                                :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
end
```

Tag Model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
 has_many :taggings
 has_many :posts, through: :taggings
end
```

Tagging Model:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: can you show your migrations files as well

Comment: Thanks Ross - My own previous migrations had broken the Acts-As-Taggable gem. I had to uninstall and start again.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of messing around I finally got this to work. Basically I had to remove all previous references to tags - particularly in the post controller and post views.

I then followed the steps described via below link to install Acts-As-Taggable gem.
http://ericlondon.com/tag/acts-as-taggable-on

```
# add acts as taggable on gem, for tagging (clearly optional)
# edit file: Gemfile
+gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'

# execute bundle to install gems
$ bundle

# create Post model
$ rails generate model Post title:string content:text

# add taggable property to Post model & make mass-assignable
# file: app/models/post.rb
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
+  attr_accessible :content, :title, :tag_list
+  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
 end

# run acts as taggable migration
$ rails generate acts_as_taggable_on:migration

# setup database
$ rake db:migrate
```

I had to remove the field called 'name' from my Posts model as this was causing a conflict the the field name 'name' in the Tags model.